# Delete an instance of a class

Tags: python, class, instance, code-organization

I've already asked a similar question here and I received quite a helpful reply. 
But since then I've modified my code, now it is more optimized I guess, it is supposed to be more flexible, but the same problem persists. I can not delete an instance of the class.

What I'm trying to do is to create a circle (on a left-click) and then I expect the program to delete the circle (on a right-click).

```
My code:

from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fen = Tk()
        self.fen.title('Rom-rom-roooooom')
        self.butt1 = Button(self.fen, text = ' Quit ', command = self.fen.quit)
        self.can1 = Canvas(self.fen, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'ivory')
        self.can1.grid(row = 1)
        self.butt1.grid(row = 2)
        self.fen.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_obj)
        self.fen.bind("<Button-3>", self.delete_obj)
        self.fen.mainloop()
    def create_obj(self, event):
        self.d = Oval()
        self.can1.create_oval(self.d.x1, self.d.y1, self.d.x2, self.d.y2, fill='red', width = 2)
    def delete_obj(self, event):
        self.can1.delete(self.d)


class Oval:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = 50
        self.y1 = 50
        self.x2 = 70
        self.y2 = 70



appp = Application()
```

so, once again, the problem is that here I can not delete the object:

```
def delete_obj(self, event):
        self.can1.delete(self.d)
```

One more question. Given the fact that I'm just a begginer I don't know if I chose the right approach as far as class organisation is concerned. Does it look like a well-organized code or should I change anything at this stage already?

Comment: I see. Should I replace the method creating a circle into to OVAL class? and then refer to it from the Application class?

Comment: I don't understand what logic you follow. You create an instance of your own class `Oval` and in parallel, another tkinter object. You never placed `self.d` on the onto `can1`. What do you need `Oval` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines:

```
self.d = Oval()
self.can1.create_oval(self.d.x1, self.d.y1, self.d.x2, self.d.y2, fill='red', width = 2)
```

create a new `Oval` object, assign that object to the name `self.d`, then create an oval on `self.can1` that is **completely unrelated** (aside from having the same dimensional attributes) from the `Oval` object assigned to `self.d`. Instead, I think you want:

```
o = Oval()
self.d = self.can1.create_oval(o.x1, o.y1, o.x2, o.y2, fill='red', width = 2)
```

This retains a reference to the object on the `Canvas`, so you will be able to `delete` it. Note that `Oval` is more-or-less-completely pointless, as all it does is provide the dimensions.

Comment: I salute you if you guessed OP's intentions right. I still don't see the purpose of oval, as it's lost almost immediately. At least it will visibly work now =). Probably the most sensible thing is to extend or wrap tkinter's oval but choosing would require a crystal ball.

Comment: @luk32 yeah, `Oval` seems to exist entirely to set the default values (they aren't even default arguments) so is a bit pointless. I will make that clearer.

Comment: thank you, it works now.
Now I do realize that it was a rather noobie fault, because oval created by the function wasn't linked to any variable and consequently as soon as this object was created, it basically dissapeared.

if I want to control the behaviour or an instance of the class OVAL, should I always have a 'pair' object? I mean like 'o' and 'self.d'. or there is a way of avoiding it?

I'm new to this object-oriented logic, sorry.

Comment: There is no real need for `o` or the `Oval` class.